# Importing multiple images in Android application

Tags: android, main-activity

How can I import multiple images on my Android app? Can I assign single id to that bundle of images to bring it from drawable? Suggest me a way.

Currently I am only able to display one image multiple times in line layout. Here is the code line to bring the image:

```
  placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture2);
```

Should I enter multiple lines for picture3,picture4,...etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
int ids[] = new int[] {
    R.drawable.picture2,
    R.drawable.picture3,
    R.drawable.picture4
};

Bitmap bitmaps[] = new Bitmap[ids.length];

for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 1){
    bitmaps[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), ids[i]);  
}
```

Also you can re-write it as a function for improving modularity.

```
public Bitmap[] loadBitmaps(int ids[]){
    Bitmap bitmaps[] = new Bitmap[ids.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 1){
        bitmaps[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), ids[i]);  
    }

    return bitmaps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Drawable store all images in Assets then you can get Image by passing name. Add following function in your activity.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String paramString)
{
    Object localObject = getResources().getAssets();
    try
    {
        Bitmap ret = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(((AssetManager)localObject).open(paramString));
        return ret;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```